# My table isn't working correctly between two communicating files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two files that make a table, one file is the table header, one is the table body. The table body isn't displaying correctly. The table header is fine, but I'm trying to import the code from the second file into the table header. It appears but it is not appearing in the table format, it only shows up as a single string.

**Note:** *These two component files are children to a separate container file as well, but I don't think the problem stems from that so I left it out.*

**Second Note:** *Also, as an intern with not too much experience, I apologize if this is simple ignorance. I tried googling it and the like, but couldn't find anything similar to my particular issue.*

Here is my code.

**File 1 (The Table Header):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Body from '../../components/prior-auth/Body';

class OrderHistory extends Component {

  render() {

return (
  <div>

    <h1>Order History</h1>

    <div>
      <table className="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Provider</th>
            <th>Client Preference</th>
            <th>Max Units</th>
            <th>Max Cost</th>
            <th>Brokered Date</th>
            <th>Begin Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <Body/>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default OrderHistory;
```

**File 2 (The Table Body):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Body extends Component {

    render () {
    return(
      <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>g</td>
            <td>h</td>
            <td>i</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
  )
 }
}


 export default Body;
```

**I don't know how to show the whole output, so here's the part that's wrong:**

The "1" describing the row, and the letters being example placeholders for the data going into each column.

> 1abcdefghi

Comment: Why do I get down voted and not helped? It's a genuine question... I thought I was being thorough.

Comment: Combine your table into one. Is that how you'd structure a table? Check out [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html). It has a good example of creating a data-responsive table in React.

Comment: It's gotta be in two separate files. I got it working, but the reason why it has to be in two files is because I have to build it to call an API and retrieve data for the table. Amongst a series of other details. Thanks though!

Comment: The combination was an exercise. If you were to combine them, what do you notice about the structure.

Comment: Oh... Oops, that completely flew over my head. Sometimes I don't slow down and read things like I should. The lack of formatting in the body was resolved by simply not using a tbody tag. Now it works fine. Is that okay to just not use a tbody tag?